# Fill radcomboBox item attributes from javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, telerik

I have a telerik radcombobox and I am using HeaderTemplate and ItemTemplte in it

Event Code

```
    <%#  DataBinder.Eval(Container, "Attributes['Event_code']")%>
```

I want to fill text , value and attribute values from javascript in this radcombo.

what curently I am Doing is :

```
        var RadComboBox1Item = new Telerik.Web.UI.RadComboBoxItem();
        RadComboBox1Item.set_text("DISPLAY TEXT");
        RadComboBox1Item.set_value("1");
        RadComboBox1Item.get_attributes().setAttribute("Event_code", "E00019");
        RadComboBox1.trackChanges();
        RadComboBox1.get_items().add(RadComboBox1Item);
        RadComboBox1.commitChanges();
```

but this code is only showing me "DISPLAY TEXT" but not the Attribute text i.e E00019

I am confused whether is there any need to change my aspx page code or javascript code so that only E00019 shold be visible in radcombo click